# Performance Tool capable of testing code for speed

Tags: performance, rpt

Is there any performance tool that has the ability to measure code speed or the time of execution for a particular function?

For example, I want to measure the speed of my Save() function.

Right now, I'm exploring IBM RPT it shows good results like Server Throughput,  Page Throughput and even live performance measurement but it cannot measure code speed.

Can anybody suggest a tool capable of doing as such?

Comment: what do you mean by "code speed"?

Answer (score 1):

Either look at Benchmarking or Profiling.

**Profiling**:

Most [IDE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) support [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)):

> In software engineering, profiling ("program profiling", "software
>   profiling") is a form of dynamic program analysis that measures, for
>   example, the space (memory) or time complexity of a program, the usage
>   of particular instructions, or the frequency and duration of function
>   calls.

The profiler measures how long each function call costs and gives you a nice report. This would be the way to check what your `Save()` function is doing for how long.

Which profiler to use is programming language depended so you need to do some research or ask a more specific question with programming language details.

Profiling more a developer task then a tester task, but performance is a key issue in software quality so understanding these concepts makes sense.

**Benchmark**:

> In computing, a [benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) is the act of running a computer program, a
>   set of programs, or other operations, in order to assess the relative
>   performance of an object, normally by running a number of standard
>   tests and trials against it. The term 'benchmark' is also mostly
>   utilized for the purposes of elaborately designed benchmarking
>   programs themselves.

In this case you may use an end-to-end testing tool and record the length of the test-case and record this as a benchmark. In the future you compare test-runs to this benchmark to see if it became slower or faster.